# Websocket error when trying to send large data (more than 2^16 bytes) in JAVA

Tags: java, websocket, server

```
private void getIncomingData(InputStream is, OutputStream os) throws IOException {

   List<ArrayList> bucket = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();

    

    while (true) {
            try {
    
                List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    
                int readed;
                while ((readed = is.read()) != -1) {
    
                    list.add(readed);
    
                    if (is.available() <= 0) {
    
                        // add to bucket with FRAMES
                        if (list.size() > 0) {
    
                            // check is final Frame
                            if (checkIsFinalFrame(list.get(0).byteValue())) {
                                this.isLastFrame = true;
                            }
    
                            System.out.println("SIZE OF list[ " + list.size() + " ]\n\n");
                            bucket.add((ArrayList) list);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
    
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                is.close();
                os.close();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

When sending data less than 2^16 first byte is **10000001**
and everything works fine.

But when data is more than 2^16 first byte is **00000001**
and no more frames are received (waiting for byte **10000001**).

For the client side is used '''var socket = new WebSocket('ws://...');'''

I can't understand what's wrong!

Comment: Divide them into chunks

Comment: How can i chunk them from the client side?